# How to derive the Bhatnagar-Gross-Krook collision integral from Boltzmann one?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let's have Boltzmann collision integral:
$$
I_{coll} =\int d \sigma d^{3}\mathbf p_{1}(ff_{1} - f{'}f{'}_{1})|\mathbf v_{rel}|.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
How to transform $\eqref{1}$ to BGK collision integral,
$$
I_{coll} = \frac{1}{\tau}(f - f_{0})?\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Here $\tau = \frac{|v_{rel}|}{l} \sim v_{rel}N\sigma $. Particularly I don't understand how to "linearize" $\eqref{1}$ for getting $\eqref{2}$.

Comment: I don't remember seeing a proper mathematical derivation of the equation (this is not to say that one does not exist). Rather, the reasoning usually goes as follows: the Boltzmann equation is known to give the Maxwellian distribution in equilibrium. The BGK equation is then a phenomenological approximation of the dynamics of the relaxation towards equilibrium (conserving the collision constants). The form of BGK is exponential, which is much simpler than the nonlinear collision integral.